# Time Series data with twice daily frequency in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

I have some data coming from sensors with observations every 12 hours. I want to analyze it as time series, but I not sure what frequency to use to convert it to time series. The `ts` function needs a start, an end and a frequency.   `ts(data, start = 1, end = numeric(), frequency = 1,...)`

I do not want to aggregate it to once daily frequency (will likely lose some information). Any recommendations?

I have posted this question on cross-validated as well [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502101/time-series-with-twice-daily-frequency-in-r). Posting it here for wider reach.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question.  It sounds like your data already are a time series.  When you say "twice a day" do you mean every 12 hours or at irregular intervals?  If the former, why isn't that the answer?  In time series analysis there is nothing magic about daily observations.

Comment: Iirc you can use the xts() function to construct a timeseries without frequency. You would only need to build your timestamps into a vector (has to be order and the data has to be in the same way as well) and use this vector as index in the xts() function

Comment: Whether you need a frequency or not depends on what you want to do with it. If you do need a frequency plot the data and see if there is a natural cycle to it and use that as the frequency.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I want to be able to decompose the time series to check seasonality etc., I have more than 2 years of data (I think it might be ok to aggregate it once a day frequency for that specific purpose). but I also want to keep it at same frequency for all analysis and make forecasts with that freq. Not too familiar with zoo yet, any suggestion on what to read? everything generally talks about daily, weekly, monthly ts etc.

Comment: Ensure that the time scale you choose is such that one frequency cycle is one time unit since the various analysis routines assume that.

Comment: @Suren That question is the same question I asked on Cross Validate but that got migrated here.. :D The answer there is helpful but there is some good information in comments here as well.